# How do I upstream a patch into the Linux kernel developed by someone else?

Tags: linux-kernel, git

I've recently been trying to upstream part of [the Nintendo Switch-on-Linux patchset](https://github.com/lakka-switch/linux), but it appears that the original developer must [sign off on each commit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/submitting-patches.html#sign-your-work-the-developer-s-certificate-of-origin).

Do I need to ask the original developers to add this? Should I add the line myself if I am submitting it?

Also, if I have to clean up/merge commits (e.g. if the originals modify semantically different files), then how should I have the original developers sign off on those?

Comment: When we say Linux is not an OS, it is a kernel. We are saying that the OS is Gnu/Linux, that is Gnu + Linux-kernel + often-other-bits. The developers of the program that you have patched, use Linux to mean Gnu/Linux. They do not mean the kernel.

Comment: or did I miss interpret it: is it Linux-the kernel on the switch?

Comment: Yes, I meant the kernel. There is a patchset that gets the Switch running Linux.